# React custom hook with useRef keeps re-rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-ref

I am working with this react custom hook to get the dimensions of the current element by useRef(). It works but It keeps re-rendering the element and I cannot find why, because `ref` is added to the dependency array of the `useEffect` hook..

[image]

```
import React, { useState, createRef } from 'react'

const useRefDimensions = (ref) => {
  const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState({ width: 1, height: 2 })
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) {
      const { current } = ref
      const boundingRect = current.getBoundingClientRect()
      const { width, height } = boundingRect
      setDimensions({ width: Math.round(width), height: Math.round(height) })
    }
  }, [ref])
  return dimensions
}

export default function Home() {
  const divRef = createRef()
  const dimensions = useRefDimensions(divRef)

  return (
    <div style={{ height: '100vh', width: '100vw' }}>
      <div
        ref={divRef}
        style={{
          margin: '50px',
          width: '70%',
          height: '70%',
          border: '1px solid black',
          display: 'flex',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}
      >
        Dimensions: {dimensions.width}w {dimensions.height}h
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is what's causing your re-renders? I just copied your code into a codepen and not getting any errors.

https://codepen.io/forbesd7/pen/oNqEwwN?editors=1111

The ref isn't changing so it shouldn't be re-rendering...I also see in your errors that GardenCanvas is causing the error (But maybe you just changed the name for this example)

Comment: Strange.. With my setup I get errors. I accidentally used a different screenshot from my actual project which gives the same errors as this prototype code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of things to consider here:

1 - Closures: `createRef` is recreated at each render so the function created on render 1 will not have deep equality with function created on render 2.

2 - Using `refs` as dependency array: Since changing a `ref` value does not make react component to re-render, it does not have too much sense to add it into a dependency array.

Here you have a couple of resources that will definitely help you udnerstand better whats wrong there:

https://tkdodo.eu/blog/hooks-dependencies-and-stale-closures

https://epicreact.dev/why-you-shouldnt-put-refs-in-a-dependency-array/

Answer (score 1):

Your code is incorrect at all, you can't keep track of element size changes like this. Right now it will re-render indefinitely because at each render a new instance of ref will be created for divRef and only the link divRef.current will be permanent - so for an fast fix you can do smtn like this:

```js
import React, { useState, createRef } from 'react'

const useRefDimensions = (ref) => {
  const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState({ width: 1, height: 2 })
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) {
      const { current } = ref
      const boundingRect = current.getBoundingClientRect()
      const { width, height } = boundingRect
      setDimensions({ width: Math.round(width), height: Math.round(height) })
    }
  }, [ref.current])
  return dimensions
}

export default function Home() {
  const divRef = createRef()
  const dimensions = useRefDimensions(divRef)

  return (
    <div style={{ height: '100vh', width: '100vw' }}>
      <div
        ref={divRef}
        style={{
          margin: '50px',
          width: '70%',
          height: '70%',
          border: '1px solid black',
          display: 'flex',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}
      >
        Dimensions: {dimensions.width}w {dimensions.height}h
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

but it will work only for the first time, so here is the same functionality code:

```js
import React, { useState, createRef } from 'react'

const useRefDimensions = (ref) => {
  const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState({ width: 1, height: 2 })
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) {
      const { current } = ref
      const boundingRect = current.getBoundingClientRect()
      const { width, height } = boundingRect
      setDimensions({ width: Math.round(width), height: Math.round(height) })
    }
  }, [])
  return dimensions
}

export default function Home() {
  const divRef = createRef()
  const dimensions = useRefDimensions(divRef)

  return (
    <div style={{ height: '100vh', width: '100vw' }}>
      <div
        ref={divRef}
        style={{
          margin: '50px',
          width: '70%',
          height: '70%',
          border: '1px solid black',
          display: 'flex',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}
      >
        Dimensions: {dimensions.width}w {dimensions.height}h
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

but if you want to keep track of element size changes - I recommend you to use libraries like this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/element-resize-detector

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
export function useRefDimensions() {
  const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState({ width: 1, height: 2   });
  const ref = useCallback((node) => {
if (node) {
  const boundingRect = node.getBoundingClientRect();
  const { width, height } = boundingRect;
  setDimensions({ width: Math.round(width), height: Math.round(height)  });
  const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver((entries) => {
    if (entries.length) {
      const boundingRect = node.getBoundingClientRect();
      const { width, height } = boundingRect;
      setDimensions({
        width: Math.round(width),
        height: Math.round(height),
      });
    }
  });
  resizeObserver.observe(node);
  return () => {
    resizeObserver.unobserve(node);
    resizeObserver.disconnect();
    };
   }
 }, []);
 return { ref, dimensions };
}
export default function Home() {
const { ref, dimensions } = useRefDimensions();
 return (
  <div style={{ height: "100vh", width: "100vw" }}>
    <div
    ref={ref}
    style={{
      margin: "50px",
      width: "70%",
      height: "70%",
      border: "1px solid black",
      display: "flex",
      justifyContent: "center",
      alignItems: "center",
    }}
   >
     Dimensions: {dimensions.width}w {dimensions.height}h
   </div>
 </div>
 );
}
```